# Can't update database using php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli

I am trying to update a user password in database with the following code

```
<?php

session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['user']) ){
}
else
{
header("location: index.php");
}
$host = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "auth_db";
$tbl_name = "users";
$link = new mysqli("$host", "$username"  , "$password", "$db_name");
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')' .msqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$pwd = $_POST['oldpass'];
$pwd1 = $_POST['newpass'];
$pwd2 = $_POST['newpass1']; 
if($pwd1 !== $pwd2)
{
Print '<script>alert("New Passwords do not match");</script>';  
Print '<script>window.location.assign("pwd.php");</script>'; 
}

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '$username'");
$user_exist = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$tbl_user = "";
$tbl_password = "";
$password = 0 ;

if($user_exist > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $tbl_user = $row['username'];
    $tbl_password = $row['password'];
    $password = password_verify($pwd, $tbl_password);
}
if(($username == $tbl_user) && ($password))
{
if($password)
{
     $new_hash = password_hash(('$pwd1'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password = '$new_hash' WHERE username = '$tbl_user'");
     Print '<script>alert("Updated, Please relogin.");</script>';
    Print '<script>window,location.assign("logout.php");</script>';

}
}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Password");</script>';
    Print '<script>window,location.assign("pwd.php");</script>';

}
}

?>
```

I am able to generate the hash but it is not getting updated in the database and the page is redirected to the given link. I am thinkinging that there is something worng with my

```
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password = '$new_hash' WHERE username = '$tbl_user'");
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $new_hash = password_hash(('$pwd1'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: nope, still dosent work. i get this error when i use mysqli_error()    "Champ 'admin' inconnu dans where clause"

Comment: The password is getting updated, but not to what is given and am also getting this error, Erreur de syntaxe pr�s de '1' � la ligne 1.

Comment: Got it, i had to change    $new_hash = password_hash(('$pwd1'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT); to     $newhash = password_hash(($_POST['newpass']), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $username  , $password, $db_name);

mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE $tbl_name SET pasword = ".$new_hash." WHERE username = ".$tbl_user.");
```

Comment: gives an error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" WHERE username = "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

your code has many syntax errors. i have cited some and put it in comments so you can change it yourself.

```
<?php

session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['user']) ){
}
else
{
header("location: index.php");
}
$host = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$db_name = "auth_db";
$tbl_name = "users";
$link = new mysqli("$host", "$username"  , "$password", "$db_name");
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().')' .msqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$pwd = $_POST['oldpass'];
$pwd1 = $_POST['newpass'];
$pwd2 = $_POST['newpass1']; 
if($pwd1 !== $pwd2)
{
Print '<script>alert("New Passwords do not match");</script>';  
Print '<script>window.location.assign("pwd.php");</script>'; 
}

$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '$username'");
$user_exist = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$tbl_user = ""; // instead of reinitializing these as a blank slate just use the unset(); function
$tbl_password = ""; // so its unset($tbl_user); so you can save memory.
$password = 0 ;

if($user_exist > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $tbl_user = $row['username'];
    $tbl_password = $row['password'];
    $password = password_verify($pwd, $tbl_password);
}
if(($username == $tbl_user) && ($password))
{
if($password)
{
     $new_hash = password_hash(('$pwd1'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
     mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE $tbl_name SET password = '$new_hash' WHERE username = '$tbl_user'");
     Print '<script>alert("Updated, Please relogin.");</script>';
    Print '<script>window,location.assign("logout.php");</script>'; //<- window.location.assign();

}
}
else
{
    Print '<script>alert("Incorrect Password");</script>';
    Print '<script>window,location.assign("pwd.php");</script>'; //<-- window.location.assign();

}
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work  by changing $new_hash = password_hash(('$pwd1'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT); to $new_hash = password_hash(($_POST['newpass']), PASSWORD_BCRYPT); , but wierdly. window,location.assign() worked same as window.location.assign().

Comment: good to hear you got it to work :) the reason it didn't work with hash(('$pwd1',password_bcrypt); is because you put quotation in **('$pwd1')** :D need sharp eyes for these little syntax errors! grats making it work